# The Monte Carlo Method For Simulation Example Problem

Tags: probability, monte-carlo, simulation

Q: A person has 5 neckties and randomly selects one tie each workday.
In a given workweek of 5 days, find the probability that the person
will wear the same tie two or more days a week.

A: Use the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 on a die to represent the ties.
Ignore any sixes. Roll the die five times for each week and count
any time you get the same number twice as selecting the same tie
twice.

In the context of answer, is counting means writing down a number(tie) that has appeared multiple times in each week or counting how many times a certain number(tie) has appeared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your stated problem, "counting" is counting weeks where any tie was chosen twice.

After you do your trials, rolling the dice for X number of week sequences, you will end up with a number of weeks that a tie was chosen twice / number of week sequences you ran for your Monte Carlo series, and this value will be your estimated probability that in a future week a tie will be chosen twice.

The idea of Monte Carlo simulations is that when you have some sort of random set of events that are too large (or perhaps infinite) to exhaustively calculate all finite probabilities, so by running a number of random tests you can start to approximate the probability.   The larger your number of tests, the better the approximation is.

Your particular assigned problem is pretty straightforward to calculate exhaustively, though to list out the 3125 different permutations would be a bit tedious.  What the assignment is trying to show you is how many "weeks" you have to simulate to start to approach the final probability.

Comment: But in the answer, it is stating that I have to count every number/tie that has appeared multiple times in each week but not counting weeks


for example:
if I roll 5 dices for the first week and I get the following result
S={1,2,3,3,4}
Then '3' is the number I need to count but I am confused about do I have to write down the number '3' or the number of times the '3' has appeared ?

Comment: @ProBoy Remember, your goal is "find the probability that the person will wear the same tie two or more days a week".   In your comment example case, {1,2,3,3,4}, you count this Week as +1 because "yes, they wore the same tie more than once.   For example, you roll 5 weeks {1,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,2,3,5}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4}, and {2,3,5,5,5}.    in this case 4 weeks out of the 5 a tie was worn more than once.  If you stopped your Monte Carlo tests there you would answer your goal question as 4/5 = 0.8 = 80%.

Comment: Thanks for the help,
Now I understood